# SharePoint Online Date field with calculated default is emptied after an update

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

On a Document Library, I have a Date field with a calculated default of `Today+90`.  This works as expected - for example, if I create a new document on "25/06/2019", the calculated default is `23/09/2019`.

The problem occurs when I make changes to the Document's metadata after it the document is initially uploaded, using the SharePoint Online 'Details Pane'.  If I change any *other* metadata field (besides the Date field), this Date field is inexplicably emptied when making that change - leaving the date field blank.

This only seems to occur after the first update.  If I manually repopulate the date field, it will stay populated afterwards.  However, this is rendering my default value useless, and I don't want to have to calculate the 90 days addition manually.

Does anybody know what's going on here?  Thanks in advance.

Edit: This doesn't occur with PDF files, only Office files!  Could this have something to do with property promotion/demotion?

Comment: hi, how do you create the calculated field with a formula [Today]+90? Per my knowledge and tests, Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me

Comment: It's not a calculated column, it's a calculated default on a date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check yes for "Require that this column contains information" in column settings.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue - the field is still automatically blanked out, but at least now it prompts "Enter value here".

Comment: Update - this issue only occurs with Microsoft Office documents.  If I use PDF files (for example), the field stays populated correctly.